# Python TypedDict 'a' or 'b' but not both in inherited TypedDict's

Tags: python, python-typing, python-3.10, typeddict

I have some data coming in that could look like

```
{"cloud_url": "https://example.com/file.txt", "filetype": "txt"}
```

or it could look like

```
{"local_filepath": "./file.csv", "filetype": "csv", "delimeter": ","}
```

for my typing I currently have

```
from typing import Literal, TypedDict

class _FileLocal(TypedDict):
    local_filepath: str

class _FileCloud(TypedDict):
    cloud_url: str

_FileCloudOrLocal = _FileLocal | _FileCloud

class _FileTextProcess(_FileCloudOrLocal):
    filetype: Literal['txt']

class _FileCSVProcess(_FileCloudOrLocal):
    filetype: Literal['csv']
    delimeter: str

FileProcess = _FileTextProcess | _FileCSVProcess
```

the issue with this version is that `_FileTextProcess` can't inherit from a union (a class has to inherit from a class)

how can I specify that `local_filepath` **or** `cloud_url` *but not both* must be supplied

Comment: mypy gives the error `Invalid base class "_FileCloudOrLocal"`. pylance gives the error `Argument to class must be a base class`

Comment: could you provide a MRE?

Comment: @leaf_yakitori I've updated the code to stand alone, and you'll be able to reproduce the error with `mypy name_of_file.py`

Comment: ok now I can try to solve the problem

Comment: I would flatten the structures and accept the duplication of some fields. Inheritance wont work for a discriminated union of base-classes nicely. IMO whatever DRY approach is conceived is likely to be more of a maintenance burden than some simpler boilerplate.

Comment: Maybe you can try [Pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic)

Answer (score 1):

my current workaround is to create a class for each possible combination, but obviously this isn't feasible for anything much more complex than this

```
from typing import Literal, TypedDict


class _FileLocal(TypedDict):
    local_filepath: str

class _FileCloud(TypedDict):
    cloud_url: str

class _FileTextProcess(TypedDict):
    filetype: Literal['txt']

class _FileCSVProcess(TypedDict):
    filetype: Literal['csv']
    delimeter: str

class A(_FileLocal, _FileTextProcess): pass
class B(_FileLocal, _FileCSVProcess): pass
class C(_FileCloud, _FileTextProcess): pass
class D(_FileCloud, _FileCSVProcess): pass

FileProcess = A | B | C | D
```

Comment: @leaf_yakitori Writing an answer to your own question is completely valid. Do not duplicate their work.

Comment: @flakes I didn't copy or duplicate his answer, just got same idea and write it in the same time. OP is faster than me about 180seconds.

Answer (score 0):

- just use `Multiple Inheritance`
- in python `Multiple Inheritance` should be

```
class MultiDerived(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
```

Not `|`

- I make it feasible so that you can apply any 2 parent class to it.
- example code:

```
from typing import Literal, TypedDict
import itertools

class _FileLocal(TypedDict):
    local_filepath: str

class _FileCloud(TypedDict):
    cloud_url: str

class _FileTextProcess(TypedDict):
    filetype: Literal['txt']

class _FileCSVProcess(TypedDict):
    filetype: Literal['csv']
    delimeter: str

def create_process(base1,base2):
    class MyClass(base1,base2):
        pass
    return MyClass

FileProcess = None
for element in itertools.product([_FileLocal,_FileCloud], [_FileTextProcess, _FileCSVProcess]):
    FileProcess = create_process(*element) if FileProcess == None else FileProcess | create_process(*element)
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. This allows both `cloud_url` and `local_filepath` keys to be specified in the final classes, which would be invalid. OP is looking for a better way to construct tagged/discriminated unions using typeddicts

Comment: that loop isn't going to work with static analysis, which is the whole point here